# Binning a python pandas dataframe: extracting bin centers and the sum of another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, binning

I am having a bit of trouble binning a pandas dataframe and then extracting the necessary plotting variables.

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
            a    ad    td  price  result  profit_loss  
12935   10809 -1181  2363    262     1.0     616743.0  
13025  -18771   696  1390    350     1.0       1390.0  
13079  -20154   348   695    305     0.0        695.0  
13085    2370  3945  3150    264     0.0    -828450.0
```

I want to bin the rows of the dataframe into equal sized bins of the "td" field (e.g. td = 0-100, 100-200, 200-300) and calculate the sum of all the profit_loss entries that fall into that td bin

e.g. here, for a td bin from 0-2000 the profit_loss would be 1390+695.

I then want to plot the td bin centers versus the profit_loss sums.

I have tried:

```
bins = np.linspace(df.td.min(), df.td.max(), 10)
groups = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.td, bins))
```

But I'm not sure how to extract the td bin centers and profit_loss sums created and plot them.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to plot empty bins as well?

Comment: Yes please @MaxU !

Comment: I've added an answer - is that what you want?

Comment: @MaxU - yes! thanks! I am just trying to understand exactly what is going on with all the 100s - see comment on your answer

Answer (score 1):

## Add *bin* column to the dataframe and then *groupby*

A *bin* shall be `td - td%binsize` (`+ binsize/2` if you want centers).

Then just *groupby* over *bin* and you can plot

```
>>> df['bin'] = df.td - df.td % 2000 + 1000
>>> s = df[['bin', 'profit_loss']].groupby('bin').sum()
>>> s
      profit_loss
bin              
1000       2085.0
3000    -211707.0
>>> s.plot(kind='bar')
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fce4fba3358>
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Small follow up question.... What is the syntax to now grab the bin centers for plotting?

Comment: @SamGregson add only `.plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show all the empty bins on the X-axis - you can do it this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

new = pd.DataFrame({'td':range(0, int(round(df.td.max() / 100) * 100) + 100, 100)})

(pd.merge(new, df.groupby(df.td//100*100)['profit_loss']
                 .sum().reset_index(),
          how='left')
   .fillna(0)
   .set_index('td')
   .plot.bar()
)
plt.axhline(0, color='k')
```

[image]

explanation:

a helper DF, containing all bins

```
In [68]: new
Out[68]:
      td
0      0
1    100
2    200
3    300
4    400
5    500
6    600
7    700
8    800
9    900
10  1000
11  1100
12  1200
13  1300
14  1400
15  1500
16  1600
17  1700
18  1800
19  1900
20  2000
21  2100
22  2200
23  2300
24  2400
25  2500
26  2600
27  2700
28  2800
29  2900
30  3000
31  3100
32  3200
```

grouped original DF

```
In [71]: df.groupby(df.td//100*100)['profit_loss'].sum().reset_index()
Out[71]:
     td  profit_loss
0   600        695.0
1  1300       1390.0
2  2300     616743.0
3  3100    -828450.0
```

merged / resulting DF

```
In [69]: (pd.merge(new, df.groupby(df.td//100*100)['profit_loss']
   ....:                  .sum().reset_index(),
   ....:           how='left')
   ....:    .fillna(0)
   ....: )
Out[69]:
      td  profit_loss
0      0          0.0
1    100          0.0
2    200          0.0
3    300          0.0
4    400          0.0
5    500          0.0
6    600        695.0
7    700          0.0
8    800          0.0
9    900          0.0
10  1000          0.0
11  1100          0.0
12  1200          0.0
13  1300       1390.0
14  1400          0.0
15  1500          0.0
16  1600          0.0
17  1700          0.0
18  1800          0.0
19  1900          0.0
20  2000          0.0
21  2100          0.0
22  2200          0.0
23  2300     616743.0
24  2400          0.0
25  2500          0.0
26  2600          0.0
27  2700          0.0
28  2800          0.0
29  2900          0.0
30  3000          0.0
31  3100    -828450.0
32  3200          0.0
```

Comment: Looks like it works beautifully, Thanks, @maxu! Now checking/understanding exactly what it is doing...

Comment: Thanks! and I definitely will. I appreciate the help massively!

Comment: What if I wanted bins of size "s". My initial thought was that all the 100s -> s. Also, the floor division in the groupby confuses me slightly. Sorry for the bother, I just want to understand this thoroughly so I don't have to bother anyone else!

Comment: @SamGregson, what do you mean saying: ` I wanted bins of size "s"`? If `s` is `100` in your question, just replace `100` with `s` everywhere... About integer division - you can play with it and see the result set without plotting - see the 2. step in the explanation

Comment: Yep - that was my question. I've played around and can see what it does! Thanks again! :)